# =sort filter including minimum value Google Spreadsheet

Tags: forms, sorting, google-sheets, graph

I hope you can help me. At this moment I am busy with creating a presentation with an auto updated graph. In this graph I will show the top 5 latest scores of people that are attending a competition. The values will be added via a google form but the score will be added later in the google spreadsheet.

The problem at this moment is that it also shows input with '0' value. I need to have the values visible once it is higher than '0'.

Does anyone know how this is possible to manage? :)

See example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cld9sU51Xf78fR14RH7gGlPNkz1Z7732DD5leQwweb4/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!
KR Sami

Comment: use QUERY or FILTER to eliminate zeroes and then create a graph from that

Comment: As Player0  has said you can make another range from your original one, removing all the values that you don want to include. But I could not find where in the sheet where is this problem reproducing, so maybe if you could provide a clearer example so we can give you a functional solution.